# Как запрограммировать блютуз модуль HC-05?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Нужно запрограммировать устройство, чтобы при получении сигнала от Android зажигался светодиод, нужно сделать отдельное устройство (подключенное к источнику питания), без плат Arduino. Как это запрограммировать?

Comment: купи в магазине. проще будет. "люблю содержательные вопросы"

Comment: вам тут вряд ли помогут. Слишком специфический у вас вопрос.

Comment: @Blaskin, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: вот такой есть запрос в гугл    
https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=hc-05

Comment: Собрать на каком-нибудь другом контроллере? Не заморачивайтесь, используйте arduino.

Answer (score 1):

«Без плат Arduino» — очень интересное требование. :) Та же Arduino Pro Mini (или просто Pro Mini в китайских магазинах) это ни что иное, как плата с микроконтроллером, цепью для работы генератора и парой индикаторов, т.е. почти минимально возможная конструкция с микроконтроллером.

Насколько я помню, общение с Bluetooth-модулем осуществляется по протоколу RS232. Вы можете взять любой подходящий для вас микроконтроллер, имеющий встроенную реализацию RS232, или использовать программную реализацию для этого контроллера. Но в принципе, чего-то совершенно отличного от Arduino Pro Mini или Nano вы все равно не получите.

Более точно можно будет ответить уже когда вы определитесь с аппаратной частью.

Answer (score 0):

[Видеоурок по управлению релюшками со смартфона](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZDsiIgH2RA)

> Уникальность этого урока в том что Ардуино или какой-нибудь микроконтроллер **нам не понадобится**, мы это будем делать **силами самих bluetooth модулей**

Вот ещё по теме, описано как его программировать: 
http://habrahabr.ru/post/125214/